# Malicious hidden in root partition

Tags: root-access, partitions, hidden

Hello everyone :) excuse me for creating a new thread but i couldnt find any info on this matter.

As a gift, my parents brought Samsung galaxy s4 from someone i dont trust who sells it. I factory reset the phone thinking its enough to clean everything. 
After a while i feel unsafe because the person knows things out of nowhere and i found out many $py software are more advanced now that its installed via root and very stealth.

I read wiping the partition and flashing the rom could help. But limited to only boot, data, cache, system while other such as /misc, /recovery remain the same?

What if its hidden in there. i want to make sure just to be safe. On a side note the person is a techie and also know im careful and observant.

Whats your suggestion on this?

Please help. Any inputs will be very much appreciated. :(
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The *Galaxy S4* is a well supported device. So a safe approach would be [flashing a clean ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info) as well as a [custom recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info). That should cover everything – as it's unlikely the radio image has been modified as well.

Comment: Stock Samsung ROMs generally include the radio image as well.

Comment: Thank your for your post :)However, do you think its really gonna wipe everything or is it better with the nand erase all? The difference is the pit file right? Which it uses for repartition. Ive read some people write tutorial. Im wavering. Because i read for full wipe and more secure we should use the nand erase all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to "flash" the firmware on the phone to stock firmware to overwrite *everything* (including system files) that you had on it before.

Go to **http://www.sammobile.com/** and enter your device model number. You'll be directed to a long list of each country variant of every Android version made for the device. If you have a preference for version, (AKA you hate 5.0 Lollipop), then download 4.4 Kitkat. This is a good 3 hour download, and you may have to download it multiple times before you get a perfect download (MD5 matching file). Also, sammobile requires you to sign up before you download. It's not a big deal, I used my real e-mail.

You will then download **[Odin v3 from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/themes-apps/27-08-2013-odin-3-09-odin-1-85-versions-t2189539)** onto your computer as well as the **[Samsung USB Drivers (Official link)](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)** and install each.

Boot your phone to Download Mode (by pressing <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume down</kbd>) and hook it up to your computer. You'll then click on the `PDA` button in Odin and find your `.tar` file. If your download is a `.zip` you'll have to extract the zip. If you're below Windows 7, the zip extraction wizard will appear to have frozen for about 10 minutes. It takes much longer than usual with a single .tar file.

Make sure all the checked boxes are as so:

[image: Odin screenshot]

..And flash!

When finished, it may or may not boot right up! If not, go into stock recovery (by pressing <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume up</kbd>) and "Clear Dalvik Cache". Now, your phone should be up and running. If not, clear data as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank your for your post :)However, do you think its really gonna wipe everything or is it better with the nand erase all?
The difference is the pit file right? Which it uses for repartition. 
Ive read some people write tutorial.

Im wavering. Because i read for full wipe and more secure we should use the nand erase all.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible to erase the entire file system from Philz recovery before flashing custom ROMs, but then your bootloader will be gone, and you won't be able to get into download mode. You'll be fine with a "clear data" after you flash.

Comment: The PIT file is good to use, but you have to be 100% sure it matches your model number.

Comment: Thanks for responding :) I google the pit file for i9500 samsung galaxy s4. And found some. So i guess it will be ok? I also google if os version makes a difference or not, but no info on that? Also i read you can also extract pit file.

Comment: Yes, they depend on Android version! Don't bother using the PIT file if you're not absolutely 100% sure. Sammobile firmwares are built to not use a PIT file. Some ROMs on XDA have a PIT file included which was verified for that ROM, for the purpose of increasing `/system` space for the additional features.